# batch insert takes only one query and fails to take all the query in java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

i have a method which has to insert into two tables, i have used batch insert for that.
my problem is it takes the second query and inserts in to that table and fails to insert into first table that is `fails to take first query`.

this is what is my code :

```
public String saveVillageDetails(VillagesViewModel viewmodel, String functionType) {
        int[] saveOrupdateStatus = null;
        StringBuffer disctrictQuery = new StringBuffer();
        String saveOrupdateStatusMessage = "";
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement districtPS = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        if (connection != null) {

            try {
                 connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                 if(functionType.equals("add")){
                    // to insert in villages table
                        disctrictQuery.append(" INSERT INTO m_villages(districtid,village,creation_date,last_created_by) ");
                        disctrictQuery.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?,?) ");
                        districtPS = connection.prepareStatement(disctrictQuery.toString());
                        districtPS.setInt(1, viewmodel.getDistrictid());
                        districtPS.setString(2, viewmodel.getVillage());
                        districtPS.setTimestamp(3, getCurrentDate());
                        districtPS.setInt(4,viewmodel.getUserid());
                        districtPS.addBatch();
                        // to insert in regions table
                        disctrictQuery=new StringBuffer();
                        disctrictQuery.append(" INSERT INTO m_regions(villageid,creation_date,last_created_by) ");
                        disctrictQuery.append(" VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
                        districtPS = connection.prepareStatement(disctrictQuery.toString());
                        districtPS.setInt(1, getLatestVilalgeID());
                        districtPS.setTimestamp(2, getCurrentDate());
                        districtPS.setInt(3,viewmodel.getUserid());
                        districtPS.addBatch();

                    }else if(functionType.equals("edit")){
                        // to update villages table
                        disctrictQuery.append("UPDATE m_villages SET districtid=? ,village=? ,updation_date=? ,last_updated_by=? ");
                        disctrictQuery.append(" WHERE villageid=? ");
                        districtPS = connection.prepareStatement(disctrictQuery.toString());
                        districtPS.setInt(1, viewmodel.getDistrictid());
                        districtPS.setString(2, viewmodel.getVillage());
                        districtPS.setTimestamp(3, getCurrentDate());
                        districtPS.setInt(4,viewmodel.getUserid());
                        districtPS.setInt(5,viewmodel.getVillageid());
                        districtPS.addBatch();
                        disctrictQuery=new StringBuffer();
                        // to update regiions table
                        disctrictQuery.append("UPDATE m_regions SET villageid=?,updation_date=? ,last_updated_by=? ");
                        disctrictQuery.append(" WHERE regionid=? ");
                        districtPS = connection.prepareStatement(disctrictQuery.toString());
                        districtPS.setInt(1, viewmodel.getVillageid());
                        districtPS.setTimestamp(2, getCurrentDate());
                        districtPS.setInt(3,viewmodel.getUserid());
                        districtPS.setInt(4,getRegionID(viewmodel.getVillageid()));
                        districtPS.addBatch();

                    }
                saveOrupdateStatus = districtPS.executeBatch();

                if (saveOrupdateStatus.length > 0) {
                    if(functionType.equals("add")){
                         saveOrupdateStatusMessage = "Village Details Added successfully";
                    }else if(functionType.equals("edit")){
                        saveOrupdateStatusMessage = "Village Details Modified successfully";
                    }
                    connection.commit();
                    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
                } else {
                     if(functionType.equals("add")){
                         saveOrupdateStatusMessage = "Failed to Add Village Details";
                    }else if(functionType.equals("edit")){
                        saveOrupdateStatusMessage = "Failded to Modify Village Details";
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //use log to print the exception    ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                closeConnection(connection, rs, districtPS);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //use logger here
            }
        }
    }
    return saveOrupdateStatusMessage;
}
```

when i printed the statement i get like this :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement[2] -  INSERT INTO m_regions(villageid,creation_date,last_created_by)  VALUES (18, '2012-11-06 17:41:25', 1)
```

and the first query is missing in the batch.

what could be the problem.

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refactor your code in the way as below:

```
            if(functionType.equals("add")){
                // to insert in villages table
                districtPS = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO m_villages(districtid,village,creation_date,last_created_by)  VALUES (?, ?, ?,?) ", 
                        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                districtPS.setInt(1, viewmodel.getDistrictid());
                districtPS.setString(2, viewmodel.getVillage());
                districtPS.setTimestamp(3, getCurrentDate());
                districtPS.setInt(4,viewmodel.getUserid());
                districtPS.executeUpdate();
                ResultSet keySet = districtPS.getGeneratedKeys();
                int villageId = 0;
                if (keySet.next()) {
                    villageId = keySet.getInt(1);
                }
                // to insert in regions table
                districtPS = connection.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO m_regions(villageid,creation_date,last_created_by)  VALUES (?, ?, ?) ", 
                        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                districtPS.setInt(1, villageId);
                districtPS.setTimestamp(2, getCurrentDate());
                districtPS.setInt(3,viewmodel.getUserid());
                districtPS.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. do you mean this way `PreparedStatement villageandRegionPS = null;
        PreparedStatement regionPS = null;
        PreparedStatement villagePS = null;`

Comment: Thanks, it is not home work, once the record is inserted into first table, i have to take id from the first table and insert the same into second table. I am sorry since i am new to this, i am struggling and running out of time also. Please help

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again and again but i have no other go other than asking you, Please

Comment: still, you need to close districtsPS right before creation of new one, just to avoid resource leaks.